# Rendering large amounts of ActiveRecord objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, performance, activerecord

I've got a few Rails controller actions that respond to AJAX requests in this fashion:

```
books = Book.all
render :json => { :books => books }
```

This should be relatively quick, however it's taking upwards of 5 seconds, which is far too long for any request on the web. The logs look like this:

```
Completed 200 OK in 5212ms (Views: 2679.7ms | ActiveRecord: 147.7ms)
```

I don't understand how the 2.6 seconds can be spent in the "views" when I'm not rendering to a view file, or how 5212ms can be spent in total. What's taking so much time, and how would one go about speeding things up?

Edit: There are about 1000 books returned in this particular request, and I'd guess each is about 1kb of data. Edit 2: Looking at the response in the console, the size of the response is 973kb.

Comment: How many books are there? How big is the response?

Comment: have you tried `respond_with(Book.all)`?

Comment: No I haven't tried that. Is it faster for some reason? I'll read up on it now.

Comment: You could also try some other json builders than rails' internal one. They might be faster. It might be that rails' internal json builder is simply slow by design.

Comment: How come nobody reads the original question? Look at his ActiveRecord time (148ms) vs View rendering time (2700 ms. That's almost 3 seconds!). It's not a data access performance issue, it's the performance of the JSON render.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [oj](https://github.com/ohler55/oj) for a faster json generation ? According to its author:

> So far is has achieved that at about 2 time faster than Yajl for parsing and 3 or more times faster writing JSON.

Maybe a good solution ?

Answer (score 1):

See Chapter 1.3 Retrieving Multiple Objects in Batches: http://goo.gl/UR5B.

Also, you might want to look into eager loading the records.

Comment: As you can see from his log output, ActiveRecord portion took very little time. It's all the view rendering that is killing performance. It seems like Rails chokes on rendering large objects to JSON. I'm seeing a similar issue in a project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've preloaded all your models that are used to render the view, you can optimize the generation of the JSON.  What you have above (render :json => {:books => books}) is not very fast.

Take a look at this question: [What is the fastest way to render json in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451722/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-render-json-in-rails)

And consider switching to a different way of rendering JSON.

Comment: And if you want to make it really fast and your books don't change that often, you can cache the results, but thats a whole other question / approach.