# What is the fastest way to render json in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I'm optimizing some slow transactions in our Rails application and a I see significant time spent rendering JSON views:

```
Rendered welcome/index.json.rabl (490.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1174ms (Views: 479.6ms | ActiveRecord: 27.8ms)
```

Assuming that the API call is returning exactly the data it needs to return, **What is the fastest way to render JSON in rails?**

We are using [Rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) because of the ability to share code easily, but we aren't tied to it.

Comment: The easiest way to speed things up is to ensure that all the data required by the view has been loaded by the controller. Often, slow views are caused by looking up associations that weren't eager-loaded.

Comment: Note that the active record time is 27.8ms, its not a lot of data here.  We do a lot of eager loading using .includes or other techniques.  I am curious where the 700ms that isn't views or ActiveRecord is spent, but thats a different question.

Comment: Turning on caching in Rabl and switching to yajl brought the time down significantly for the second request:

Rendered welcome/index.json.rabl (321.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 893ms (Views: 311.0ms | ActiveRecord: 27.2ms)

Comment: @JohnNaegle Were you able to figure out where the other 700s where being spent as part of your response call ? If yes, what do you suggest is the best way to track this ?

Comment: I have not - I'd love to know exactly where that time is being spent.

Comment: @JohnNaegle Any update on the solution, if you found any? Rails 4 also has same issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rabl uses `multi_json` for compatibility across platforms and doesn't use the quite fast Yajl library by default. Rabl's [config documentation](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#configuration) explains the solution:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'yajl-ruby', :require => "yajl"
```

In the event that still isn't performant enough, you might want to explore a different JSON serializer like [oj](https://github.com/ohler55/oj). You could [also instrument](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html) your render and see where the bottleneck exists.

Comment: I read the "also instrument" link, and don't see how that translates into finding performance problems, at least not easily. What were you thinking?

Comment: Rob, perhaps this screencast might shed some light. http://railscasts.com/episodes/249-notifications-in-rails-3?autoplay=true    regards.

Answer (score 45):

Currently [oj](https://github.com/ohler55/oj) seems to be the fastest renderer - beating yajl (according to the oj author's [comparison](https://github.com/ohler55/oj#comparisons)).

Oj is used by default in the latest multi_json (and rails uses mutli_json by default), so swapping to oj should be as simple as adding the following to your Gemfile:

```
  # Gemfile
  gem "oj"
```

Then each time you call render, it will now use oj.

```
  render :json => { ... } # uses multi_json which uses oj
```

Oj also provides additional specific interfaces, if you want even more performance, but sticking to multi_json makes it easier to swap out gems in the future.

Note that if you have any `{ ... }.to_json` calls - these will not be upgraded to use oj unless you call `Oj.mimic_JSON` in an initializer.

Comment: I tried putting Oj.mimic_JSON in an initializer, but it raises and error about JSON is already required. Is there another step where I take to stop the requiring of JSON module somewhere? Thank You

Comment: Based on my testing, Oj is much faster than multi_json.

Answer (score 17):

Rails 3 uses multi_json, but it only uses it for **json decoding, not encoding**. Json encoding/rendering/generation uses ActiveSupport JSON library's `to_json` method, therefore is always slow (even if you uses Oj gem).

You can explicitly rendering using multi_json by doing:

```
render :json => MultiJson.dump(@posts)
```

Or you can try [rails-patch-json-encode gem](https://github.com/GoodLife/rails-patch-json-encode) (by me) which will use multi_json by default. It will affect all build-in `to_json` methods, so make sure all the tests passes.

Comment: whoa! `MultiJson::dump` is super fast! thanks for mentioning this

Answer (score 0):

Netflix recently released a new JSON rendering library which is supposedly 25-40 times faster than the default library. [Announcement](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/fast-json-api-serialization-with-ruby-on-rails-7c06578ad17f). [Code](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi). You'll need to create a new Serializer to take advantage of it, but for people who are impacted, that doesn't seem to be a big hurdle.

Comment: fast_jsonapi follows http://jsonapi.org conventions. Thus you will never construct your json the way you want. You can't get rid of "data", "relationships" and other wrappers around the data. See [this github issue](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi/issues/204)

Comment: fast_jsonapi  is too opinionated. I don't recommend this library if one wants to construct JSON output the way he/she wants.