# Append attributes to model object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-activerecord

I have a `Place` model and a `PlacesController`. Currently the controller responds to JSON with certain objects. I would like to add more fields to the responded objects. For example, I would like to add every place's tags, queried by the method `Place.tags`.

I'm thinking in two solutions: convert the list of objects to a list of hashes and add the attributes that I want, or add a new column in the model, filling it in the controller iterating the list of objects. I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; don't `Place`s already have an association with their tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming:

```
 class Place < ActiveRecord:Base
   has_many :tags
```

If so, are you simply trying to add the associated tags to the place object's json?  If so, you can use (where 'place' is a Place object):

```
 place.to_json(:include=>:tags)
```

Comment: +1; this is the correct answer if the models are associated correctly (which they should be).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a template to generate the JSON as well.  It will give you control over what appears in your JSON and is significantly faster than rendering via to_json or render :json.

Check out my question about the fastest way to render JSON here: [What is the fastest way to render json in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451722/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-render-json-in-rails).

I've found RABL (https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) to be fast and easy to set up.

For your example, in RABL, you would do something like this:

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @place = Place.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

And in the view:

```
object @place => :place
attributes :id, :name

children :tags => :tags do
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation I would probably use the presenter pattern. Take a look here: http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/rails-presenter-pattern.html

There's also a railscast if you have a pro account: http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about my solution is the better way

```
# in controller
@place = Place.first
@place[:place_tags] = @place.tags.map(&:attributes)
render :json => @place
```