# Rails and Angularjs Slow Query Result on Autocomplete field

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am using rails with angular and I've created a live search input field. I'm troubleshooting why the query takes around 1.5 seconds inside the browser but only 23 milliseconds when running the exact same query directly from the mysql console.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

here's what I have:

products_controller.rb

```
def getProducts
  @product_results=Product.searchProduct(params[:term])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @product_results}
  end
end
```

product.rb

```
def self.searchProduct(search)
  if search
    where('product_name LIKE :column or product_code like :column', :column => "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

results in the query:

```
SELECT * `products` 
WHERE (product_name LIKE '%example%' or product_code like '%example%')
```

routes.rb

```
resources :products do
  get :getProducts, :on => :collection
end
```

product.html: This is where the magic comes in. I'm using a directive developed by these guys https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt

```
<angucomplete-alt id="ex1"
   placeholder="Search Products"
   pause="100"
   selected-object="selectedProduct"
   remote-url="products/getProducts?term="
   remote-url-data-field="products"
   title-field="product_name"
   minlength="1"
   input-class="form-control form-control-small">
 </angucomplete-alt>
```

Here's what I've noticed.  If you are typing in the input field and the query is interrupted it resets the query.  Not sure if this has something to do with it.  The view renders in .6 seconds but ActiveRecord still takes 1 second to complete.

console:

```
Started GET "/products/getProducts?term=12%20oz" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-16 11:25:07 -0400
[2015-03-16 11:25:07] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:20
/Users/ctilley83/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `eof?'
/Users/ctilley83/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/ctilley83/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
Processing by ProductsController#getProducts as JSON
  Parameters: {"term"=>"12 oz"}
  Product Load (1.0ms)  SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE (product_name LIKE '%12 oz%' or product_code like '%12 oz%')
Completed 200 OK in 622ms (Views: 620.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Comment: It looks as though your template for `render json: @product_results` is the slow part. Is the JSON that you're building/returning bulky? You might consider looking into either simplifying the results (and perhaps adding a `limit` to your query), or increasing the speed of JSON render ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/10509638/624590 ). Or both!

Comment: As @DRobinson wrote, the query is not the slow part. It only takes 1 ms according to your log.

Comment: The table is only 250 records.  I've also tried to pull only 2 table fields with only a 20% improvement.  the query generally returns less than 20 results so I'm not certain that will help.  I'll look into your linked post and see if that helps

Comment: JSON rendering can be pretty slow in Rails, particularly if those Objects are complex. It might be a good idea to try subsets of the key-value pairs in your JSON template, find out if any of them are particularly slow.

Comment: MultiJson is deprecated but the docs say to use to use to_json.  `format.json {  render json: @product_results.to_json  }` completely reduced the query to 2ms.